# Split comma separated string to array

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngfor

I have a string of comma separated values like

`let options = '1, FIRST,2, SECOND,3, THIRD,4, FOURTH'`

Requirement: There will be a space after first comma which is next to number. I need to split comma only after each word.

I need to convert this options to array in Angular html to show it in dropdown

```
<mat-select #  multiple>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options.split(',')" [value]="option">{{option }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Expected result:

```
1, FIRST
2, SECOND
3, THIRD
4, FOURTH
```

What I got with split(,) is

```
1
FIRST
2
SECOND
3
THIRD
4
FOURTH
```

**Updated Question:**
I tried the solution provided here,

```
let options = '1, FIRST,2, SECOND,3, THIRD,4, FOURTH';
let splitOptions = options.split(/,(?=\d)/);
let splitOptionsWithQuotes = options.split('/^,(?=\d)$/');

for (let options of splitOptions) {
console.log(options);
}

for (let options of splitOptionsWithQuotes) {
console.log(options);
}
```

```
options.split(/,(?=\d)/) is working in TypeScript compiler. 
Output:
[LOG]: "1, FIRST" 
[LOG]: "2, SECOND" 
[LOG]: "3, THIRD" 
[LOG]: "4, FOURTH"
```

```
options.split('/,(?=\d)/') is not working in HTML or TypeScript compiler. This results in 
[LOG]: "1, FIRST,2, SECOND,3, THIRD,4, FOURTH"
```

Putting regex in single quotes not working in html. I tried executing the same in typescriptlang-org online compiler

Comment: doesn't seem like you can do it easily. You may have to make a method in the TypeScript part. Easiest way being a regex...

Comment: I tried regex. Mostly it works in Typescript, but same code not works in Angular html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you want to have an array with properties "value" and "text"

```
  const options='1, FIRST,2, SECOND,3, THIRD,4, FOURTH'
  const optionsArray=options.split(',').reduce(
          (a:{value:number,text:string}[],
           b:string,
           i:number)=>{
                if (i%2)
                   a[Math.floor(i/2)].text=b.trim();
                else
                   a.push({value:+b,text:''})
           return a
          },[])
```

then optionsArray becomes like

```
[ { "value": 1, "text": "FIRST" }, { "value": 2, "text": "SECOND" }, 
  { "value": 3, "text": "THIRD" }, { "value": 4, "text": "FOURTH" } ]
```

**Update**
If we want an array like

```
[ "1, FIRST", "2, SECOND", "3, THIRD", "4, FOURTH" ]
```

We can use

```
optionsArray=options.replace(/\,(\d)/g,"|$1").split('|')
```

First repalce the ","+digit by "|"+digit and then split by "|"

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kuejw9?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

**Update 2**, when we have a select with options it's a good idea that the select was "feed" with an array of object with two properties: "value" and "text".

So I suggest

```
  rankings: Array<ColumnType> = [
    {
      id: 'schoolRanking',
      options: this.schoolOptions.map((x) => {
        const pair = x.split(',');
        return { value: +pair[0], text: pair[1] };
      }),
    },
    {
      id: 'collegeUGRanking',
      options: this.collegeUGOptions.map((x) => {
        const pair = x.split(',');
        return { value: pair[0], text: pair[1] };
      }),
    },
    {
      id: 'levels',
      options: this.collegePGOptions.map((x) => ({ value: x, text: x })),
    },
  ];
  allRankingss = this.rankings.map((x) => x.id);
```

We define a rakningForm like

```
  rankingForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    schoolRanking: new FormControl(0),
    collegeUGRanking: new FormControl(''),
    levels: new FormControl(''),
  });
```

And our .html becomes more easy

```
<div [formGroup]="rankingForm">
  <table mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container
      [matColumnDef]="ranking"
      *ngFor="let ranking of allRankingss;let i=index"
    >
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [id]="ranking">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select [formControlName]="ranking" placeholder="Dropdown">
            <mat-option
              *ngFor="let rank of rankings[i].options"
              [value]="rank.value"
            >
              {{ rank.text }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-header-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row
      *matHeaderRowDef="allRankingss; sticky: true"
    ></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: allRankingss"></mat-row>
  </table>
</div>
```

see your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-teiowz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Findex.html)

Comment: I need 1, FIRST as a separate word to show as a single text in dropdown. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `<option [value]="option.value">{{option.value+' '+option.text}}</option>`. But this "split" in value and text it's only if you want store "the value" (1,2,3,...). If you want to store "1, FIRST" (or "2, SECOND"), you can use some like `optionsArray=options.replace(/\,(\d)/g,"|$1").split('|')` -first replace the ,digit by |digit and after you use split (I update the answer)

Comment: options.replace(/\,(\d)/g,"|$1").split('|') has to be escaped with quotes in html like

options.replace('/\,(\d)/g', '|$1').split('|'), but in html it is not working. may be I need to add some pipe.

Comment: I added stackblitz https://angular-ivy-dctyfk.stackblitz.io here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dctyfk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

the options: [...this.schoolOptions]  is returning as a comma separated string instead of array, as I returned ${col.options}-filter. If it returns as an array there is no need to split by comma to convert it as array.

Comment: Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'LEVELA,LEVELB,LEVELC,LEVELD' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays.

options: [] returns as this string instead of array. so I have added .split(',') to convert it as array. It beats me with the special case '1, FIRST, 2, SECOND'

Comment: @Abhikhya, you need take account if your variables are arrays or strings. At very first you talk about string, but your stackblitz are arrays. Take a look to my answer updated

Comment: I changed {{ rank.text }}  to {{ rank.value +""+ rank.text }}  and 
changed
 options: this.collegePGOptions.map((x) => ({ value: x, text: x })), to  options: this.collegePGOptions.map((x) => ({ value: '', text: x })). It works now, but this last collegePGOptions dropdown's first option is set as first default item. I will accept the answer. Please edit the changes. Thank you.

Comment: For last collegePGOptions dropdown's first option is set as first default item issue I have modified to {{ (rank.value || '' ) + rank.text }} . It works.

Comment: Also removed value from
options: this.collegePGOptions.map((x) => ({ text: x }))

Forked stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w4ls5u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: As you already returned array here  *ngFor="let rank of rankings[i].options", you don't need to split comma. Just iterating rankings[i].options will give the desired result  '1, FIRST, 2, SECOND'. Great thanks for the solution.